# I can't set the BackgroundColor of a StackView in iOS 12 or older

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I'm trying to set a backgroundColor of a StackView and it works on iOS 13 or newer, but on iOS 12 it's a complete failure. Maybe it's related to darkMode although I don't use any related settings.

I tried to set the color in VidDidLoad() and it didn't work either, I'm kind of lost, I looked for other similar questions, none were the same

ViewCode

```
final class PaymentCashViewCode: UIView, ViewCodeProtocol {
var salesValueComponent: UIStackView = {
    let view = UIStackView()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: .greyRhino)
    view.isLayoutMarginsRelativeArrangement = true
    view.axis = .vertical
    return view
}() 
}
```

ViewController

```
class PaymentCashViewController: UIViewController {
var mainView = PaymentCashViewCode()

func setupComponents() {
    self.view.addAttrachedSubView(view: mainView)
    self.title = viewModel.getViewControllerTitle()
    mainView.delegate = self
    mainView.setTextFieldDelegate(delegate: self)
    mainView.setTextFieldFocus()
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prior to **iOS 14** stack views were "non-rendering" views -- that is, they only arranged their subviews.

Starting with **iOS 14** you can set the background color.

If you need a background color for earlier versions, you need to embed the stack view in, or place it on top of, a `UIView`

Comment: it worked dude, thanks. A question how did you know that? I didn't find this information easy in the documentation, do you know where it is exactly or was it because of keeping up with Apple's continuous updates like WWDC for example?

Comment: @Podrosa - I've been doing this since 1990... after a while, you just "know stuff." :) I'm sure it was documented *somewhere* although I've never been able to find it. As recently as Nov 22, 2021 (according to "WayBackMachine"), Apple's docs page still showed `The UIStackView is a nonrendering subclass of UIView;` ... that line is no longer there. I **do remember being surprised** the first time I saw a piece of code that set `.backgroundColor` on a stack view and it *worked*!

Comment: wow, 32 years is a lot of history, I searched here and found the line on "WayBackMachine" that you commented, it made a lot more sense to me now, cool man, thanks for the help and sharing your knowledge, it's always good to be inspired by the elders lol.